# Как правильно написать этот код?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть переопределенная функция, которая на всех экранах одна и та же...

Не могу догадаться, можно ли как то сделать рефактор, чтоб не повторять ее на каждом активити?

И как быть с переменной `drawer` в этом случае?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen()) {
        drawer.closeDrawer();
    } else {

        if (backPressedQ == 1) {
            backPressedQ = 0;
            super.onBackPressed();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);

        } else {
            backPressedQ++;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //Обнуление счётчика через 5 секунд
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
                backPressedQ = 0;
                //checkNew();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
class BaseActivity extends Activity
{
    ...

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Далее все нужные нужные активити наследуем от него:

```
class FirstActivity extends BaseActivity
{
    ...
}

class SecondActivity extends BaseActivity
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Добавьте небольшое пояснение, думаю, просто этого фрагмента кода автору для понимания недостаточно

Comment: @metalurgus а какое описание добавить... А вы как думаете можно ли в этом случае как то правильно сделать рефактор или нужно его дублировать на каждом активити?